# How do I open local files using heidiSQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm using [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) to access my remote MySQL db.

Recently I was sent an .sql file.

Is there a way to open this file using HeidiSQL?
Does anyone know of a better way to **graphically** view and manipulate a local sql file?

I know that in windows Heidi associates with sql files but when double clicked nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This part lifted from my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39429/how-to-import-data-from-a-pair-of-mdf-ldf-files-into-a-mysql-database/39434#39434)...)

The first thing to note is that an `.sql` file is not a MySQL database. It is a script file containing SQL statements. You would run such a script against the database platform for which it was written (using the SQL dialect for a specific SQL database engine) to create the actual database.

---

From comments to other answer:

> I was wondering if there is a way on Heidi or another program to do this without setting up a server.

No, you need a server *somewhere*. If there was any stand-alone tool that could "graphically manipulate" an `.sql` file (containing DDL, I presume) then it would have to have its own MySQL server embedded in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course just use any text editor such as Notepad to edit the SQL file and then paste the result in the `Query` screen indicated here: http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=query

Make sure though that you use an ANSI text editor and that if you have any non standard characters, that they are pasted correctly.

Comment: Nice idea, but this is a pretty big file ~10Mb

Comment: I would assume that the file does a lot more than just one or two queries.  Is there any reason you cannot use the normal mySQL tools?

Comment: I could and probably will use phpMyAdmin but I was wondering if there is a way on Heidi or another program to do this without setting up a server.

Comment: Well, you would certainly not have to set up a server just to install the mySQL Workbench (would you?) --> http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

Comment: @hitautodestruct : I just downloaded this tool, and it looks like from the `Tools` menu, you can select `Load SQL File`.  Have you tried that option yet?

Comment: Just tried it but it still needs a connection to a db.

Comment: Another option is perhaps use a tool such as NotePad++ (plus plus)?  From the Language menu you can set it to SQL.  I have used it tonnes of times to manipulate SQL files without a server connection, but you will not have the added benefit of properly parsing it without a connection to a server.   http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8281/discussion-between-hitautodestruct-and-roka)